# Wifi with ESP 8266 or 32

Tags: wifi, micropython

I need your help because I don't understand what's going on. I have 2 esp8266 , one in AP mode and the second in station mode.
When I connect the ESP in station mode to my box, it's ok.
On the other hand when I use this code to connect to the other ESP in AP mode with a fixed IP, the ESP remains in the while loop

```
import network
from time import sleep

def config_wifi():
    ip        = '192.168.144.3'
    subnet    = '255.255.255.0'
    gateway   = '192.168.144.1'
    dns       = '8.8.8.8'
    ssid = 'MicroPython-AP'
    password = '123456789'
    ap=network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
    ap.active(False)
    ap.disconnect()  
    print(ap.status()) # return None
    sleep(2)
    sta=network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    sta.active(True)
    sta.disconnect() # for ESP8266
    sta.connect(ssid,password)
    print(sta.status())# return 1001 : CONNEXION
    sleep(2) 
    while (sta.isconnected()==False):
        print(sta.isconnected())
    sta.ifconfig((ip,subnet,gateway,dns))
    ip=sta.ifconfig()[0] 
    print('Connected',ip)
    return ip

def run():
    config_wifi()
    
run()
```

Following my tests, I used an ESP32 Lolin with this program and I have the same result, ie False in the while loop.
The first status gives me None and the second 1001. Searching on different forums, 1001 means Connexion.
Status indicates that there is connection, on the other hand the while loop gives False
I do not understand Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use static ip on esp32 in micropython move `ifconfig` part before `active(True)`

```
sta.ifconfig((ip,subnet,gateway,dns))
sta.active(True)
```